# How to reduce PieChart border size(width) in amcharts4?

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

How to reduce PieChart border size(width) in amcharts like shown below? I want to reduce the first chart border size(width) like second one. I already set **innerRadius** property to 100 percent.

[image: Image 1]  [image: Image 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to increase both the `innerRadius` and `radius` to a large enough value to make the circle skinnier.

```
chart.innerRadius = am4core.percent(100);
chart.radius = am4core.percent(100);
```

Demo:

```js
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.PieChart);

chart.data = [{
  "category": "",
  "value": 100
}];

chart.innerRadius = am4core.percent(100)
chart.radius = am4core.percent(100) 

var pieSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
pieSeries.dataFields.value = "value";
pieSeries.dataFields.category = "category";
pieSeries.ticks.template.disabled = true;
pieSeries.labels.template.disabled = true;
var label = pieSeries.createChild(am4core.Label)
label.text = "100%";
label.horizontalCenter = "middle";
label.verticalCenter = "middle";
label.fontSize = "2em";
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I tried this also but below two configurations along with radius disappear chart.  series.slices.template.strokeWidth = 0; series.slices.template.strokeOpacity = 0;